# Rolled out app update is stuck at "processing update" for 3 days

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

For our app that has 100M+ downloads and millions of active users, we follow a weekly update schedule.

After publishing the latest update, with no major architectural change or anything, the update is stuck with a "processing update" or something. 
It's been 3 days (yes days, not hours) like this.

Playstore analysis, as well as our in-house analytics, is showing 0 installs or usage for the new version.

Any clue how can we approach this?

[image]

And, this is the third time it's happening. The first time, we talked to the "support" team who provided us with zero new information, and ofc with no resolution.

Then how did we get out of the stagnant situation the previous times? 
We submitted the same build, but just with different, increased version; and it worked and rolled out normally.
This time the trick seems like not working anymore.

Comment: facing the same issue. How did you resolve it?

Comment: @TanayMondal it isn't really. With every update, it's getting worse.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, approaching 5 days now.

Comment: This is due to [this](https://www.choiceofgames.com/2019/08/google-warns-developers-that-all-new-apps-require-three-days-for-approval/)